# How to plot multiple files, same format with headers (11 lines) and 4 columns spaced by \t

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am just starting with python for plotting. My goal is to plot 35 files in the same graph. All the files have the same structure:

11 lines of headers that must be skipped.
4 columns separated by tab:

```
Headers
'
'
(11) lines

data11    data12    data13    data14
data21    data22    data23    data24
'
'
------------------------------dataij
```

I would like to know  what is the easiest way of doing that. I also wanted to chose the columns (x being column 0 and y being columns 1)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and show us the code that you use trying to get those files read in.